# Python code to multiple JSON files with different names

Tags: python, json

I'm new to `python` and programming in general, asking for help: What to run in `python` code to print this data in multiple `JSON` files (300 files) that every file change the "name" line from #1 to #300 and the `JSON` files names will be like from `1.json` to `300.json`
is it possible?

```
{
  "description": "#", 
  "image": "#", 
  "name": "#1",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "#", 
      "value": "#"
    } 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Show us your code.

Comment: This is the code that i want to it to appear in the json files : {
  "description": "#", 
  "image": "#", 
  "name": "#1",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "#", 
      "value": "#"
    } 
    ] 
}

Comment: Sure, it’s possible. Use an f-string (or the like) to fill in the `name` in the JSON snippet and then print it using the standard Python file API, e.g. in a loop over a `range(1, 301)` or the like. As a side note, it would be way easier to generate the files directly in Bash; simple file operations (redirections) are *way* shorter there than in Python, e.g. `for ((i = 1; i <= 300; ++i)); do printf "${JSON_TEMPLATE}" "$i" > "${i}.json"; done`. What `JSON_TEMPLATE` should be is probably obvious (and it would have `%d` somewhere in it to fill in the number).

Comment: thank you @AndrejPodzimek I get the idea but I can't understand the way to do it like how json file will be created and where to put these codes, can you please show me the code if it's not too long?

Comment: @Anis That's simply a Bash snippet / one-liner. Put it in a script file or run it directly, as you prefer. The `JSON_TEMPLATE` variable should have your JSON stuff assigned to it, verbatim, so e.g. `JSON_TEMPLATE='{ ... name: "#%d", ... }'` etc. (You can have newlines in quotes in Bash, no problem at all. (Or in Python you would use the `'''` / `"""` string literal type if you decide to go with Python. (Or, even better, a JSON-aware library, as someone already pointed out.)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
# library to work with json stuff
import json

# you can create dict first represent the json
json_dict = {
  "description": "#", 
  "image": "#", 
  "name": "#1",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "#", 
      "value": "#"
    } 
    ] 
}

# define numbers of file you want to create
n = 300
for i in range(1, n+1):
    # change the "name" atribute for every iteration
    # you can use f-string method
    json_dict["name"] = f"#{i}"

    # save the dict to file
    # again, use the f-string to name the file
    with open(f"{i}.json", 'w') as json_file:
        #json.dump() method save dict json to file
        json.dump(json_dict, json_file)
```